# Turn off Information Popup

Tags: toad, auditing

In Toad for Oracle 12.7.1.11, every time I open a synonym in Schema Browser with the Script tab selected, I see the same annoying popup, with this text:

```
To extract audit options, you must either have SELECT privilege on DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS or log into the schema that you are extracting.
```

Could someone kindly tell me how to get rid of it? (Note: I don't seem to get the popup when I open the table the synonym is for with a different DB user.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on the Toad for Oracle forum (
http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/) and got the correct answer back! For those interested:

Click the first button in the script tab. In the dialog that appears, uncheck "Audit Statements".